Windows Power Control Options - Sleep, Hibernate, Disk off, Screen off, hybrid sleep
I'm trying to better understand the power control options in windows, especially for a laptop.
Under control panel power options I see several settings related to sleep, hibernate, screen off and hdd off. It seems to me that hibernate and sleep should not be used together, but maybe I'm missing somthing.
Look at the following example:

Screen off after 5 minutes
Hard Disk off after 10 minutes
Sleep after 15 minutes
Hibernate after 20 minutes
If the hard disk is off after 10 minutes, will the computer still try to sleep or hibernate?
The system will never automatically go into hibernate because it goes to sleep first. However the user could manually trigger hibernation.

What about hybrid sleep?
